# xcode - Sharing code between Framework and Workspace

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, workspace

I have a Framework and a Workspace (project + pods). I want the framework to use classes of workspace (both the project and the pods). Then, when I'll distribute my framework, I need it to have references to the above classes. How do I do that?

Comment: have you had a chance to try my solution?

Comment: How to do this if I want a specific class to be shared between a project and a framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoapods provides the means to add a dependancy to a pod. So for example a cocoapod I write could require the project to have the latest `AFNetworking` cocoapod installed. I can also require other frameworks to be used such as `CoreLocation`, `CoreBluetooth` etc.

If you create your framework as a cocoapod you should be able to add a list of dependencies that will be added when you run:

`pod install`

I've created a framework as a pod before and used something like this in my podspec:

```
s.source              =  { :git => ' <destination Git repo> ', :tag => '0.0.1' }
s.ios.xcconfig        =  { 'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/<MyFrameWorkName>"' }
s.ios.preserve_paths  =  '<MyFrameWorkName>.framework'
```

You then should be able to require that cocoapod to have other dependancies, for example:

```
s.frameworks   = 'QuartzCore'

s.ios.weak_frameworks =  'CoreBluetooth'

s.dependency 'SDWebImage',                  '~> 3.7'
s.dependency 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK',     '3.0.3c'
```

Now when you / someone else installs your framework through cocoapods, they will have everything they need installed in the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new workspace including all of them, by writing a podfile in that way:

```
workspace 'AllInOne.xcworkspace'
xcodeproj 'Workspace/Workspace.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'Framework/Framework.xcodeproj'

target 'ProjectA' do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  xcodeproj 'Workspace/Workspace.xcodeproj'
  pod 'nameofpod', '~> .1'
end

target 'Framework' do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  xcodeproj 'Framework/Framework.xcodeproj'
end
```

**EDIT:**

Create a new folder (with name for example "AllInOne"). In that folder place your framework folder, where into that exists the framework.xcodeproj, and also place your workspace folder.
Now, create the podfile in the AllInOne folder. At the end should exist these files in this dir:

AllInOne/Workspace/Workspace.xcodeproj

AllInOne/Framework/Framework.xcodeproj

AllInOne/podfile

AllInOne/AllInOne.xcworkspace

Comment: Can I have more details? Should I just drag the framework in the existing workspace? Should I only add a section in podfile for the framework? What will be supplied to the user when the framework is ready? Only the framework and the bundle files?

Comment: >> pod install >> Analysing dependencies >> [!]Unable to find a target named 'ProjectA' (my project name)